# Determine definition and parameter of a Scheme function in the interpreter? / How are functions stored in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I want to create a function that can determine the definition of an arbitrary function in scheme. If we call such a function "definition", it would work as such:

```
(define (triple x) (* 3 x))

(definition triple) would return "(triple x) (* 3 x)".
```

There would be some implementation problems (such as with n-arity), but I'm concerned mostly with whether or not the definition of individual functions are easily retrievable in Scheme.

As a continuation, is there a way to create a function that can determine the parameters of an arbitrary function? Such that:

`(parameters +)` returns `(number number)` or something similar.

These questions both fall under the question of how functions are stored in Scheme - I found some sources which claimed that function definitions are stored with the function name, but I couldn't find out how exactly they were stored.

If this is impossible - is there a language where function definitions are easily retrievable?

Comment: There's no standard introspection mechanism in Scheme. There might be implementation-dependent ways to do it, check the documentation for your Scheme interpreter.

Comment: Thanks - I think it's kind of odd that Scheme wouldn't have introspection since I thought the whole LISP family was about reflection, but I guess that's how it goes.

Comment: @user124577 Actually, Lisp languages are _not_ huge into reflection at all. Lisp's hallmark is macros, which generate code (usually from some kind of template) rather than pry into existing code.

Comment: Also, many Lisp (and Scheme) systems compile a lambda expression immediately (usually into an intermediate form rather than straight into object code) and don't retain the original source. For such implementations, you would not be able to recover the original code.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: I think that's a difference to Scheme. Several Common Lisp variants have a lot of support for reflection. From code-as-data to the Meta-Object Protocol of CLOS.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like that in Scheme. Individual implementations might have that, though.

In Common Lisp there is the standard function `function-lambda-expression`, which might be able to retrieve source code - depending on the implementation.

Example in LispWorks (reformatted to improve readability here):

```
CL-USER 65 > (defun triple (x) (* 3 x))
TRIPLE

CL-USER 66 > (function-lambda-expression #'triple)
(LAMBDA (X)
  (DECLARE (SYSTEM::SOURCE-LEVEL #<EQ Hash Table{0} 42201D392B>))
  (DECLARE (LAMBDA-NAME TRIPLE))
  (* 3 X))
NIL
TRIPLE
```

SBCL:

```
* (defun triple (x) (* 3 x))

TRIPLE
* (function-lambda-expression #'triple)

(SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA TRIPLE
    (X)
  (BLOCK TRIPLE (* 3 X)))
NIL
TRIPLE
```

As you can see it returns three values: the code, whether it is a closure and the name of the function.